# How do you define firefox exe path in selenium with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use selenium Firefox with powershell and I need to specify the firefox's executable (portable firefox). I can make my script work with chrome and I have found how to specify chrome's path but I had no luck with Firefox.
Here's all I got so far:

```
# Website and credential variables
$YourURL = "http://192.168.0.1/" # Website we'll access

# Invoke Selenium into our script!
# Geckodriver.exe
$env:PATH += ";D:\Powershell\webdriver" 
Add-Type -Path "D:\Powershell\webdriver\WebDriver.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "D:\Powershell\webdriver\WebDriver.Support.dll" 


$ff_object = New-Object "OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver"
```

Comment: I don't think you need to specify a path to Firefox (assuming you installed Firefox on your machine). Just make sure Geckodriver.exe is in the same folder with WebDriver.dll

Comment: That is the reason I have posted I do not want to install Firefox. I need a portable version that will be available over a shared folder.

Comment: This is possible, though I don’t use PowerShell enough to be able to craft an answer at the moment as I’m on mobile. What you want is the `FirefoxOptions` object, specifically, the `BrowserExecutableLocation` property. The `FirefoxDriver` class has a constructor that takes an options argument.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot JimEvans! Here is my powershell working code:

```
$YourURL = "http://192.168.0.1/" # Website we'll access

$env:PATH += "C:\Users\Carl\Desktop\webdriver\" # Adds the path for ChromeDriver.exe to the environmental variable 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Users\Carl\Desktop\webdriver\WebDriver.dll" # Adding Selenium's .NET assembly (dll) to access it's classes in this PowerShell session

$FirefoxOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxOptions
$FirefoxOptions.BrowserExecutableLocation = "D:\PortableApps\FirefoxPortable\App\Firefox64\firefox.exe"
$FirefoxDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver($FirefoxOptions) 

# Make use of Selenium's class methods to manage our browser at will
$FirefoxDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl($YourURL) # Browse to the specified website
```